# What is correct way to update ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::Translation within ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, strong-parameters, acts-as-taggable-on, globalize

I'm trying to register model ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::Translation to allow translation of tags.
For correct usage of strong parameters I followed manual https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
which states

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :title, :content, :publisher_id
end
```

I've tried different ways and all of them doesn't allow to update parameters.

This:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::Translation, :as => "TagTranslation" do
  permit_params :name, :tag_id, :locale
end
```

And this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::Translation, :as => "TagTranslation" do
  permit_params acts_as_taggable_on_tag_translation: [:name, :tag_id, :locale]
end
```

And even this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::Translation, :as => "TagTranslation" do
  controller do
    def permit_params
      params.permit! # allow all parameters
#      params.permit acts_as_taggable_on_tag_translation: [:name, :tag_id, :locale]
#      params.require(:acts_as_taggable_on_tag_translation).permit(:name, :tag_id, :locale)
    end
  end
end
```

What I'm doing wrong?